# How to allow only machines with specified ip to login via ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, networking, permissions, sftp

I want to allow only machines with allowed ip(s) to login to my system via ssh.

For example, `userA` can use only ip `xx.xx.xx.xx` or `yy.yy.yy.yy` to login via ssh, and no other ip can login as the `userA`. And `userB` can use only ip `zz.zz.zz.zz` to login via ssh, no ip other than  `zz.zz.zz.zz` can login as `userB`.

How should I set up my Linux to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit SSH access to specific clients by IP address](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/406245/limit-ssh-access-to-specific-clients-by-ip-address)

Comment: Specifically, [tonioc's answer](/a/490120/112566) and [iBug's answer](/a/563452/112566) both address this use-case.

Answer (score 10):

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` add the following:

```
AllowUsers remoteUserA@xx.xx.xx.xx remoteUserA@yy.yy.yy.yy userA
AllowUsers remoteUserB@zz.zz.zz.zz userB
```

Then restart the SSH daemon.

You can use wildcards as described in **Patterns** section of the [ssh_config manual](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config).

Comment: What if I'm not sure the username of the remoteUser? I want anybody via zz.zz.zz.zz to be able to login as userB. Your method seems that require explicitly specify the username of the remoteUser.

Comment: Use a wildcard `*@xx.xx.xx.xx`

Comment: @MarcusThornton: `*@yy.yy.yy.yy` should work, according to `man sshd_config` (see: AllowUsers) and `man ssh_config` (see: Patterns)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that via iptables.

All connections from address 1.2.3.4 to SSH (port 22):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --source 1.2.3.4 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Deny all other SSH connections:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

Comment: Iptables will not enough by it self. The best result if will add into /etc/ssh/sshd_config AllowUsers A B and no passwords, only ssh keys.

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with the basic markup used on this site. Using headerlines like you did and not formatting code as such leads to horribly formatted, ugly, posts. (click on the "edited ..." link to see how things changed.

Comment: @user6780 you should [edit] your answer instead of commenting.

Answer (score 0):

One approach (if you're using PAM for authentication) is to specifiy `pam_rhosts` as a `required` module in `/etc/pam.d/ssh`.  This allows each user to specify in their own `.rhosts` file where they are permitted to connect from.

Note that the authentication modules in the `pam.d` file will not be consulted for pubkey logins (e.g. I have `auth required pam_deny.so` to prevent password logins on my machines).  Other modules (`account`, `session` and so on) are still used.