# Limit SSH access to specific clients by IP address

Tags: linux, firewall, sshd

How do we allow certain set of Private IPs to enter through SSH login(RSA key pair) into Linux Server?

Comment: Firewall rules are a normal course of action to take

Comment: firewall or /etc/hosts.allow if ssh compile w/ TCP wrappers or /etc/ssh/sshd_config file rules.

Comment: more than one way to do, refer to https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config which explains everything in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can limit which hosts can connect by configuring [TCP wrappers](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/en/man5/hosts.allow.5.html) or filtering network traffic (firewalling) using [iptables](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/iptables.8.html). If you want to use different authentication methods depending on the client IP address, configure SSH daemon instead (option 3).

### Option 1: Filtering with IPTABLES

Iptables rules are evaluated in order, until first match.

For example, to allow traffic from 192.168.0.0/24 network and otherwise drop the traffic (to port 22). The `DROP` rule is not required if your iptables default policy is configured to `DROP`.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 --source 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

You can add more rules before the drop rule to match more networks/hosts. If you have a lot of networks or host addresses, you should use [*ipset*](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/iptables-extensions.8.html) module. There is also [*iprange*](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/iptables-extensions.8.html) module which allows using any arbitrary range of IP addresses.

Iptables are not persistent across reboots. You need to configure some mechanism to restore iptables on boot.

`iptables` apply only to IPv4 traffic. Systems which have ssh listening to IPv6 address the necessary configuration can be done with `ip6tables`.

### Option 2: Using TCP wrappers

*Note: this might not be an option on modern distributions, as support for tcpwrappers was removed from [OpenSSH 6.7](https://lwn.net/Articles/615173/.)*

You can also configure which hosts can connect using TCP wrappers. With TCP wrappers, in addition to IP addresses you can also use hostnames in rules.

By default, deny all hosts.

`/etc/hosts.deny`:

```
sshd : ALL
```

Then list allowed hosts in hosts.allow. For example to allow network *192.168.0.0/24* and *localhost*.

`/etc/hosts.allow`:

```
sshd : 192.168.0.0/24
sshd : 127.0.0.1
sshd : [::1]
```

### Option 3: SSH daemon configuration

You can configure ssh daemon in sshd_config to use different authentication method depending on the client address/hostname. If you only want to block other hosts from connecting, you should use iptables or TCP wrappers instead.

First remove default authentication methods:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication no
```

Then add desired authentication methods after a `Match Address` in the end of the file. Placing `Match` in the end of the file is important, since all the configuration lines after it are placed inside the conditional block until the next `Match` line. For example:

```
Match Address 127.0.0.*
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

Other clients are still able to connect, but logins will fail because there is no available authentication methods.

Match arguments and allowed conditional configuration options are documented in  [sshd_config man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man5/sshd_config.5.html). Match patterns are documented in [ssh_config man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man5/ssh_config.5.html#contenttoc3).

Comment: What about adding a ListenAddress directive in /etc/ssh/sshd_config ?

Comment: It is possible in specific situations (for example listening to private network address), depending on your network configuration and which hosts you want to allow.

Comment: Additionally, ,sshd_config can set filterings with AlowUsers directive, and also, the authorized_keys can be set with 'from IP or subnet" to filter also.

Comment: @tonioc Great solution for my use case. Please expand this suggestion into an answer.

Comment: if you have a NIC with 4 ports each going to a different network, then the default `#ListenAddress ::` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` will tell the SSH server to accept incoming from any of those networks.  Otherwise do `ListenAddress <ip address>` where `<ip address>` is that of those NIC ports you want allowed.  My `eth0`is `192.168.3.4` therefore `ListenAddress 192.168.3.4` results in SSH only working on network 192.168.3.4 which is on eth0; and eth1 eth2 eth3 is denied.

Comment: In `hosts.allow`, `192.168.0.0/24` may not work, but `192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0` works

Comment: Note that `sshd` must be linked against `libwrap` for TCP wrappers to work (see e.g. [here](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/understanding-tcp-wrappers-in-linux/)) and that support for tcpwrappers/libwrap was dropped from [OpenSSH in v.6.7](https://lwn.net/Articles/615173/).  On many modern systems Option 2 may no longer work.

Comment: @AstroFloyd thank you, I've added a note to the answer.

Answer (score 41):

Here some additional configuration for SSH daemon to extend previous answer:

- Add user filtering with `AllowUsers` option in `sshd_config` file:

  ```
  AllowUsers johndoe@192.168.1.* admin2@192.168.1.* otherid1 otherid2
  ```

  This allows *johndoe* and *admin2* only from `192.168.1.*` addresses and *otherid1*, *otherid2* from anywhere.
- Restrict a ssh key or ca-based key to a set of addresses in `.ssh/authorized_keys` file of a given user's home directory:

  ```
  from="192.168.1.*,192.168.2.*" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABA...etc...mnMo7n1DD useralias
  ```

  In this example, the public key for useralias will be effective only from given addresses.

Comment: In my case, white listing in sshd was better than using iptables/ufw.  The firewall was unable to keep up with traffic.  We only needed to lock down ssh, so adding AllowUsers clause to /etc/ssh/sshd_config was a much lighter weight solution.  Otherwise, you have to continuously tune your fire wall.  You also have to stress/load test the firewall and it's hard to anticipate real network traffic patterns.

Comment: The second approach is awesome because it is minimal, thank you. Small tip for the others, double quotes are mandatory even in case of single, explicit address.

Comment: `AllowUsers` also has the benefit of e.g. restricting SSH logins to a certain IP address but allowing SFTP logins from anywhere, in case you have other team members that need to access that... `hosts.allow` or firewalls would restrict both.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't mind installing UFW (Uncomplicated FireWall):

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 22
```

**Edit**: As previous mentioned it's a good practice to only authenticate using keys instead of passwords which can be done by editing [`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/sshd_config):

```bash
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM no
```

Comment: And how should the SSH login be limited to RSA key pair?

Comment: @rickhg12hs by adding your public RSA key to  `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: More is required to **restrict** login to only RSA key pair.

Comment: In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, set `PasswordAuthentication`, `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` and `UsePAM` to `no`.

Comment: It's best if you update your answer so that future readers can look for a complete answer to the original question.  I like to think about StackExchange sites as a searchable encyclopedia.  Each question and answer should try to make the encyclopedia better and easy to get more correct information.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Good suggestion, I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Another way you can limit access to sshd on a GNU/Linux system at the socket level with a built-in (assuming init is systemd 235+ and kernel 4.11+) is by utilizing systemd with cgroup/eBPF [access lists](http://0pointer.net/blog/ip-accounting-and-access-lists-with-systemd.html)

Modify the base sshd systemd stanza

```
sudo systemctl edit sshd
```

Append the sshd [Service] stanza to your liking

```
[Service]
#requires systemd 235+ and kernel 4.11+
IPAccounting=yes
IPAddressDeny=any
IPAddressAllow=192.18.1.22
IPAddressAllow=10.161.0.0/16
IPAddressAllow=100.64.0.0/24
```

reload for immediate effect

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Comment: This isn't per-user, so it won't handle the use case where I want to allow SSH and SFTP from everywhere for webuser1, webuser2, but only SSH/SFTP from 1.2.3.4 (office IP) for root (Assuming each user has their own key and password authentication is disabled).
Correct me if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using SSH CA for client authentication, you can specify the `source-address` option when signing certificates:

```bsh
ssh-keygen -s ca_privkey -O source-address=172.16.0.0/16 id_rsa.pub
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The certificate `id_rsa-cert.pub` can be used to log in to hosts only from `172.16.0.0/16` addresses (not even `127.0.0.1` unless you specify that as well).

`man 1 ssh-keygen` is a good document if you want more details.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to restrict a specific user to login in only from specific IP addresses and to specify that only public key will be accepted :

```
Match user myuser
    AllowUsers myuser@mynet1 myuser@mynet2
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
    PasswordAuthentication no
    ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
    UsePAM no
```

Comment: (1) This answer is incomplete.  What file are you talking about?  (***I*** can guess, but answers shouldn’t require guesswork.)  (2) It seems to at least overlap a lot with, and maybe even duplicate, a few previous answers.  (3) How does it ***answer*** the question?  How can the OP restrict logins by source IP address?  (I guess you mean for `mynet1` and `mynet2` to refer to host IP addresses, but, again, answers shouldn’t require guesswork.)  (4) What if the OP can’t, or doesn’t want to, list user names?  Can they say `AllowUsers @mynet1 @mynet2` or `AllowUsers *@mynet1 *@mynet2`? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (5) What do the user names on the ``AllowUsers`` line even mean in this context?  (6) Will this even do what the question asks for, or will unspecified users still be allowed to connect from anywhere? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).