# Limiting ssh connections to specific devices

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, firewall

I have an ubuntu system at home, allowed ssh and enabled port forwarding to my machine for ssh connections. So far so good.

Now I can access from everywhere.
How do i confugure my machine to refuse any connection that is not from my laptop or my phone?

Should it be done from the router or from the machine's firewall?
How do I do it?

Comment: ssh-keys!  https://askubuntu.com/questions/346857/how-do-i-force-ssh-to-only-allow-users-with-a-key-to-log-in

Comment: use ssh key to refuse at ssh level. Note that your modem/router will likely not forward incomming ssh connection (unless you advise it) from world to your server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit SSH access to specific clients by IP address](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/406245/limit-ssh-access-to-specific-clients-by-ip-address)

Answer (score 1):

How to achieve this in two steps:

## Step 1 - Whitelist

Just create a whitelist to allow the PCs you wish to allow access.

```bsh
sudo vim /etc/hosts.allow
```

then just add your computer's IP

```bsh
sshd: 10.83.33.77/32, 10.63.152.9/32
```

## Step 2 - Blacklist

Now create a blacklist to block all others

```bsh
sudo vim /etc/hosts.deny
```

now block all

```bsh
sshd: ALL
```

Comment: [TCP wrappers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_Wrappers) (included on libwrap0 package, see also `man hosts_access`) [are deprecated](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Deprecate_TCP_wrappers)

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Shōgun8 is correct, but I would like to add that there is already an answer for your question:

[Limit SSH access to specific clients by IP address](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/406245/limit-ssh-access-to-specific-clients-by-ip-address)